React Query String Works in local but redirects to 404 in production
Description:
I have a React application with a route setup to display a public profile using parameters like /profile?id=test123 or /?profile=test123. I've implemented the route using useSearchParams() and useParams() hooks.
What I've Done:

Created a route using useSearchParams() and useParams() hooks.
Implemented fetching data based on the parameters provided.

Issue:

The setup works perfectly in my local environment, and data is fetched correctly.
However, in the production environment, it redirects to a 404 page.

Code Snippets:
// PublicProfile.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { publicprofile } from '../../../../API/APIs';
import {
  Typography,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemText,
  Divider,
  Box,
} from '@mui/material';

function PublicProfile() {
  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  console.log(searchParams);
  const logSearchParams = () => {
    console.log(searchParams.get("id"));
  };
  logSearchParams();
  const [school, setSchool] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSchoolData = async () => {
      try {
        const payload = {
          query: searchParams.get("id"),
        };
        const response = await publicprofile(payload);

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch school data');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setSchool(data);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching school data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchSchoolData();
  }, [searchParams.get("id")]);

  if (!school) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Box p={2} border={1} borderRadius={4}>
      <Typography variant='h2'>{school.name}</Typography>

      <Box mt={2}>
        <Typography>
          <strong>Address:</strong> {school.address}
        </Typography>
      </Box>

      <Divider variant='middle' />

      <Box mt={2}>
        <List>
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemText
              primary={<strong>Phone:</strong>}
              secondary={school.contactDetails}
            />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Box>

      <Divider variant='middle' />

      <Box mt={2}>
        <Typography>
          <strong>Established Date:</strong> {school.establishedDate}
        </Typography>
      </Box>

      <Divider variant='middle' />

      <Box mt={2}>
        <Typography>
          <strong>Facilities:</strong> {school.facilities.join(', ')}
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      {/* Add more details as needed */}
    </Box>
  );
}

export default PublicProfile;

Route Structure:
// Routes.js
<Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
  <Route path='/' element={<LandingPage />} />
  <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
  <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
  <Route path='/forgotpassword' element={<ForgetPassword />} />
  <Route path='/validateOtp' element={<OTPValidation />} />
  <Route path='/resetpassword' element={<ResetPassword />} />
  <Route path='/profile' element={<PublicProfile />} />
</Route>
<Route path='/admin/' element={<AdminLayout />}>
  <Route path='/admin/profile' element={<AdminProfile />} />
  <Route path='/admin/school' element={<SchoolInfo />} />
  <Route
    path='/admin/createclassroom'
    element={<CreateClassroomForm />}
  />
  <Route
    path='/admin/generateInviteCode'
    element={<GenerateInviteCode />}
  />
  <Route path='/admin/createNewSchool' element={<CreateSchool />} />
  <Route path='/admin/attendance' element={<ViewAttendance />} />
</Route>

Question:
I'm trying to understand why this setup works in my local environment but redirects to a 404 page in the production environment. Any insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I'm trying to understand why this setup works in my local environment but redirects to a 404 page in the production environment. Any insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
And I expect  solution for how to use query params in react on production.
How I am Hosting My WebAPP?
it working on Linod VPS.
Its working from Debian linux with nginx server
here is conf file if you need to look at
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domainname.com;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

       location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
}

// simply put npm run build command and copy and past files to /var/www/html

package.json file after removing packages as and domainname

    {
      "name": "projectalpha",
      "private": true,
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "type": "module",
     
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
        "preview": "vite preview"
      },
      "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.3.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.40.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.40.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "html5-qrcode": "^2.3.8",
    "logrocket": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.2.10",
    "vitest": "^1.4.0"
  }
}

**

NOTE : DNS is cloudflare

**

Wherever & however you are hosting/serving the app, that hosting service/server environment needs to be setup/configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. How are you hosting/serving the app? Check these deployment docs to get a broad overview what might need to be setup/configured. In the meantime please [edit] the post to clarify how you are running the app and what the setup is. See [mcve].

Maybe you meant try_files $uri $uri/index.html;?

Use instead this for Nginx config:
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

And serve your app with serve -s build/

not sure what you really mean!!  where  "serve -s build/"   to run this command for npm nginx or  CLI in linux ?
and i hope you understand i dont only need solution i also want to understand why this happens ?
and if you provide solution please explain it
